# Static content with Jetty and Spring

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

My webapp doesn't  show any static content.

- Spring MVC
- Twitter Bootstrap
- Jetty 7

Build project:
mvn clean install with Jetty included

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Some company</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- use this for Spring Jackson JSON support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.config" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.market.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.service.app" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.controller" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                    <property name="viewClass"
                        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**hero.jsp** Added .jsp libary otherwise twitter bootstrap example but deleted some content

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]--> 

    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../resources/assets/bootstrap/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Folder structure is maven like.

```
src
- main
    - webapp
        - WEB-INF
            -jsp
            -resources
                - assets
                    -bootstrap
                        - css
                        - ico
                        - img
                        - js
        - spring-servlet.xml
        - web.xml
```

When I open the the hero.jsp as hero.html and view it in my browser I see that twitter bootstrap is working but when I deploy it nothing works...
I played around with

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

but it didn't worked...

If I looked in the source of the html file when it is deployed the link e.g. for .css points to

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

Comment: try moving resources to webapp directory. thanks

Comment: THX!! I had also to change the location from ../resources... to ../../resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Try moving resources to webapp directory*** was the right tip.